# How to render files (called in one method) after a form is called and validated from a different method?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

We are displaying the files in the gsp. The files are being pulled from the back end in the following way:

View

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Attachment:
   <td>
    <g:each in="${lstAttachment}" var="nonOracleAttachmentItem">
     <g:link id="${nonOracleAttachmentItem.Id}" action="nonOracleAttachment" params="[nonOracleAttachmentItemId: nonOracleAttachmentItem.Id,nonOracleAttachmentItemName: nonOracleAttachmentItem.Name]">${nonOracleAttachmentItem.Name}</g:link><br/>
    </g:each>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
def show(){ 
     def strAttachmentsName = null;
    def boolAttachment = objChangeControl.Attachment__c
    def strOrcAttachmentName = objChangeControl.Attachment_Name__c

    if(strOrcAttachmentName !=null){
        def lstOracleAttachment = salesforceService.getSObjectList(SFDC_ORG, "SELECT Id,Name from Attachment where ParentId='${idG}' AND Name='$strOrcAttachmentName'")
        def lstAttachment = salesforceService.getSObjectList(SFDC_ORG, "SELECT Id,Name from Attachment where ParentId='${idG}' AND Name != '$strOrcAttachmentName'")
        def oracleAttachmentId = lstOracleAttachment[0].Id
        def oracleAttachmentName = lstOracleAttachment[0].Name
        [oracleAttachmentId:oracleAttachmentId, oracleAttachmentName: oracleAttachmentName,lstAttachment:lstAttachment,grcInstance: objGRCChangeControl,updatedRAIInstance: objUpdatedRAI, strConfigurationOwner:strConfigurationOwner,strGRCStatusCustomSetting:strGRCStatusCustomSetting,sfUserName: session["${SFDC_ORG}UserName"],sfUserId:sfUserId]
    }else{
        def lstAttachment = salesforceService.getSObjectList(SFDC_ORG, "SELECT Id,Name from Attachment where ParentId='${idG}'")
        [lstAttachment:lstAttachment,grcInstance: objGRCChangeControl,updatedRAIInstance: objUpdatedRAI, strConfigurationOwner:strConfigurationOwner,strGRCStatusCustomSetting:strGRCStatusCustomSetting,sfUserName: session["${SFDC_ORG}UserName"],sfUserId:sfUserId]
    }
}
```

This is all good except when a field in the form fails validation and we need to retain all the field values along with the files that were originally displayed. Here's the catch block (inside the method called after pressing the 'Submit' button) which displays the error and also renders the values entered by the user prior to the validation error. How can I render the files as well?

```
 def submitGRCRecord(){
   try{

......
}

         catch (Exception e){
            render(action:"show",model:[sfUserName: session["${SFDC_ORG}UserName"], sfUserId: session["${SFDC_ORG}UserId"],encodedId:encodedIdParam,grcInstance: getGRCRecord(),inputITGNumber:inputITGNumber,inputJustification:inputJustification,attmtChecked: 'true',lstAttachment:params['lstAttachment']])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is very basic info but following’s the summary of this use case and solution for future reference:

User receives an email with a link/URL to the form where they need to provide certain information. The URL would always be in following format:
E.g.:
https://testchain.tstrandomurl.com/Folder1/show?encodedId=qwerty12345
The form would display some existing information from a record in database. The record id (unique identifier) is extracted from the encodedId in the URL. The existing ‘information’ includes, but is not limited to, bunch of files that needs to be displayed as a downloadable link.

Additionally, the form also has couple of fields which requires user inputs Explanation of Changes: - a long text field and Additional Related Attachments:- file upload placeholder.

Explanation of Changes has 256 character limits. This same record could be accessed multiple times and every time user needed to enter new Explanation of Changes it would count against the total character limit which incorporated previous input as well. So when the total character limit is reached, an standard error message was sent back to the view using flash.message. Additionally we had another check to cross check file name of Additional Related Attachment against pre-existing files in database.

While sending the error message after the form input validation, all the original value (except the uploaded file) needed to be retained in the form.

This was achieved by using chain method with action, params, and  model like this: `chain(action:'show',params:[encodedId:encodedIdParam],model: [UserName: session["${ORG}UserName"], UserId: session["${ORG}UserId"] ,inputExplainChanges:inputExplainChanges])`

Using chain method to call 'show' method which originally displayed the files in the form and retain user input via model:[..] the issue was resolved.